# Сформировать SQL запрос по таким условиям

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблицы:

```
1. shop_order (id, contact_id,state_id)
2. contact_data (id, contact_id, field, value)
```

Вторая таблица имеет следующий вид:

```
id | contact_id | field | value
1 | 25 | phone | 89167777777
2 | 25 | city | Москва
3 | 26 | phone | 89164444444
4 | 26 | city | Москва
5 | 27 | phone | 89163333333
6 | 27 | city | Тверь
```

Таблица shop_order

```
id | contact_id | state_id
1 | 25 | paid
2 | 26 | paid
3 | 27 | notpaid
```

Как выгрузить все заказы (shop_order) и номера телефонов контакта к этим заказам (contact_data), которые имеют shop_order.state_id='paid', и город Москва?

Comment: выгрузить в где-то в коде, в каком-то языке.. или же просто в sql manager? И предоставьте обе таблицы

Comment: @Insider просто sql запрос нужен, дополнил

Comment: @Dizzy221 https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно взять номера, думаю этот подойдет:

```
SELECT
  so.id, 
  so.contact_id.
  cdp.value
FROM shop_order so
JOIN contact_data cdc ON so.contact_id = cdc.contact_id
JOIN contact_data cdp ON so.contact_id = cdp.contact_id
WHERE so.state_id = 'paid' and cdc.value = 'Москва' and cdp.field='phone'
GROUP BY cdp.value
```

Comment: А что если заказ есть, а контакта нет?

Comment: Если будет ситуация в которой с одним номером телефона 2 заказа,  то из-за `group by value` второй заказ потеряется

Comment: @Viktorov заказ без контакта по логике приложения невозможен. Идея состояла в том чтобы главным образом вытащить номера телефонов последних заказов, так что потеря заказа тут роли не играет. Но спасибо за мнение ;)

Comment: @Dizzy221 вы так можете терять последние заказы, если этот номер телефона использовался ранее. Потестируйте)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM shop_order 
  JOIN contact_data 
    ON shop_order.contact_id = contact_data.contact_id 
 WHERE 1
```

Вроде как так должно получится

Comment: вы что-то странное тут написали. И `where 1` зачем?)

Comment: @Viktorov , WHERE 1 возьмет все значения из таблицы shop_order .. Но вариант у человека выше все равно лучше.

Comment: так с тем же успехом его можно просто не писать. И ваш вариант совершенно игнорирует, что в контактах может быть не только москва и не только телефоны. Вы просто выводите все. В общем это совсем не то